# Action bar sherlock error - Android

Tags: android

I've created an Action Bar Sherlock library project, I've added that library to my project.

I get the error:

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Im using min sdk 7, target sdk 15.

I've cleaned the project and all of my projects in eclipse.

I've restarted eclipse.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there errors in the library? Compiling errors?

Comment: No, didnt think I was supposed to?

Comment: Working with eclipse? Do you have an .jar for the ActionBarSherlock or the code?

Comment: Yes eclipse, I have a library project for Action Bar Sherlock. No jar.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+O to fix all your imports. Make sure you are using the "android support jar" that comes with ActionBarSherlock and make sure that the ActionBarSherlock is added on a project library to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps over here at :
http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/action-bar-sherlock-tutorial

and also have a look at : http://androidfragments.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-use-actionbar-sherlock.html

Also make sure you add the actionbar sherlock project to the build path of your project